# react js error in index file Cannot update a component Issue

Tags: reactjs

There is a serious issue in my react testing application. Please check the below error

```
index.js:1 Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`AppContainer`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `AppContainer`,
```

[image]

this is my index.js code

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "containers/App";
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

what is this issue. how can i fix this

Comment: Try : 
import {App} from "containers/App";

Comment: What does the App.js file look like?

Comment: post your full code. we cannot help you with this info only